# Simple generic call with return type

Tags: c#, lambda

I am currently trying to create a generic call that takes in a value that needs to be returned by the function that is being passed in. It would appear to be a simple generic method, but I for the life of me cannot figure out why it isn't working.

What I am looking to do is pass a method onto this method, so that it can call and API and handle any errors that it comes across. I want to pass a gRPC call across to the method, wrap it in a try catch then invoke and catch any errors.  I figured a generic would be the best way to accomplish this but it doesn't seem to be working. If someone has a recommendation to what will work better, I am all ears.

The generic call I came up with is super simple:

```
public T MakeCall<T>(Func<T> calling)
{
    var res = calling.Invoke();


    return res;
}
```

The calling code is as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var caller = new Caller();

    caller.MakeCall<int>(Add(1, 2));

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}

public static int Add(int one, int two)
{
    return one + two;
}
```

It is giving me an error that says,

> "int is not assignable to parameter type System.Func"

Comment: `() => Add(1, 2)` instead of `Add(1, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

```
MakeCall<int>(Add(1, 2))
```

means "*execute* `Add(1, 2)` and then call `MakeCall<int>` with the result (which is `int`)". You should put a `Func<int>`, not `int`:

```
MakeCall<int>(() => Add(1, 2))
```

Here

```
() => Add(1, 2)
```

is a `Func<int>` which takes nothing and returns `Add(1, 2)` result

Answer (score 2):

Because `Add()` returns `int` whereas `int` is not `Func<T>`. You can use `() => Add(1,2)` as a parameter.

So the solution would be

```
caller.MakeCall<int>(() => Add(1, 2));
```